# Smoovpay str_url not working

Tags: integration, payment

This time i am using my live account, but i am facing the same problem. it's not redirecting on str_url parameter. i am using the following code.

```
<form action="https://secure.smoovpay.com/access" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="pay" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="SGD" />
<input type="hidden" name="version" value="2.0" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item 1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="Description for item 1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_amount_1" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="Admin@fooderich.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="SampleReference" />
<input type="hidden" name="delivery_charge" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="tax_amount" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="tax_percentage" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="0.50" />
<input type="hidden" name="str_url" value="www.mysite.com/strurl" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="www.mysite.com/success" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="www.mysite.com/cancel" />
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="6d752252db0496ddeef15c27ca249e3cd91f85ae" /><input type="hidden" name="signature_algorithm" value="sha1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit v2" alt="SmoovPay!" />
</form>
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this line after your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="skip_success_page" value="1" />
```

be default the skip_success_page is 0 so make it 1 will redirect you to your str_url and then success_url